# Powershell. Is it possible to bind New-Item -Value parameter ByPropertyName?

Tags: powershell, object, new-item

```
Help New-item -parameter "Value"
```

show us -Value <System.Object> could be bind ByPropertyName or ByValue. The question is:

** Is it possible *pipe* ByPropertyName? **

As ByValue takes precedence over ByPropertyName, I can't find any example to be able to do that *pipe*.
Anything I write to the left is an object, and is bound by ByValue, even if that object has the -Value attribute.

Thank you

Example:

```
$customObject = [PSCustomObject]@{
    Value = "Lorem ipsum"
}

$customObject | New-Item -Name BPN_value.txt
```

The content of BPN_value.txt is @{Value = "Lorem ipsum"} because $customObject is an object (obviously) and it's binding byValue to the paramete Value of New_Item

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to bind `New-Item -Value` parameter `ByPropertyName`?

No, because as you have already noticed, the parameter type is [`System.Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object?view=net-7.0) and since all objects inherit from this class every input from pipeline is bound with [`ValueFromPipeline`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefrompipeline-argument) instead of [`ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.2#valuefrompipelinebypropertyname-argument).

##### Should the type for this parameter be other than `System.Object`?

No, because it would conflict with other [providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_providers?view=powershell-7.3). In example, defining a new function would no longer be possible:

```
$null = New-Item -Path function:Say-Hello -Value {
    'hey there'
}

Say-Hello
```

##### Should the `-Value` parameter be enabled to bind by Property Name?

Probably not, because it can never be bound by it.

##### Is there a workaround?

You could have a [ProxyCommand](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.proxycommand?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0) or *wrapper function* around `New-Item` that changes the parameter type from `System.Object` to `System.String`, this way the function would be able to work properly taking `ValueFromPipeline` and `ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName`. You could then store this wrapper in your [`$PROFILE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.2#profile) and have it available for you each time a new session is started.

**For the reasons stated before, this wrapper would only work targetting the [`FileSystem` provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_filesystem_provider?view=powershell-7.3) and has been hardcoded for `ItemType = File`.**

```
function New-File {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='pathSet', SupportsShouldProcess=$true, ConfirmImpact='Medium', HelpUri='https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=2096592')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='pathSet', Mandatory=$true, Position=0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='nameSet', Position=0, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [string[]]
        ${Path},

        [Parameter(ParameterSetName='nameSet', Mandatory=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [AllowNull()]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [string]
        ${Name},

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Alias('Target')]
        [string]
        ${Value},

        [switch]
        ${Force}
    )

    begin {
        try {
            $outBuffer = $null
            if ($PSBoundParameters.TryGetValue('OutBuffer', [ref] $outBuffer)) {
                $PSBoundParameters['OutBuffer'] = 1
            }

            $PSBoundParameters['ItemType'] = 'File'

            $wrappedCmd = $ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.GetCommand('Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\New-Item', [System.Management.Automation.CommandTypes]::Cmdlet)
            $scriptCmd = { & $wrappedCmd @PSBoundParameters }

            $steppablePipeline = $scriptCmd.GetSteppablePipeline($myInvocation.CommandOrigin)
            $steppablePipeline.Begin($PSCmdlet)
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }

    process {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.Process($Value)
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }

    end {
        try {
            $steppablePipeline.End()
        } catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }
    <#
    .ForwardHelpTargetName Microsoft.PowerShell.Management\New-Item
    .ForwardHelpCategory Cmdlet
    #>
}

[PSCustomObject]@{ Value = "Lorem ipsum" } | New-File .\BPN_value.txt -Force
"Lorem ipsum" | New-File .\BPN_value2.txt -Force
```

---

For reference, the definition of the code used above was autogenerated using:

```bash
[System.Management.Automation.ProxyCommand]::Create((Get-Command New-Item))
```

Then it has been slightly modified and simplified for this specific answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply! I have only recently started learning powershell and I find your New-File example incredible.
I don't quite understand the definition of the function, but it understands the goal of wrapping New-Item.
Thanks again!! :-)

Comment: @EduardoFernández I'm glad the answer was helpful and I'm happy to help. See my update to show you how that code used in the function can be autogenerated

Comment: I see. Really useful! I have a lot to learn :-)

Answer (score 0):

It *is* possible if the values of the `-Path` or `-Name` parameter is also a property of the object in the pipeline:

```
[PSCustomObject]@{
    name = 'TestFile'
    value = 'Hello World'
} | New-Item
```

Console capture:

```
PS ScratchPad> [PSCustomObject]@{
>>     Name = 'TestFile'
>>     value = 'Hello World'
>> } | New-Item


    Directory: C:\ScratchPad


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        11/23/2022  12:07 AM             35 TestFile
```

Or:

```
PS ScratchPad> [PSCustomObject]@{
>>     Path = "$Home\Documents\TestFile.txt"
>>     value = 'Hello World'
>> } | New-Item


    Directory: C:\Users\keith\Documents


Mode                 LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                 -------------         ------ ----
-a----        11/23/2022  12:27 AM             64 TestFile.txt
```

But for some reason, it doesn't like `-Path` + `-Name`:

```
PS ScratchPad> [PSCustomObject]@{
>>     Path = "$Home\Documents"
>>     Name = 'TestFile'
>>     value = 'Hello World'
>> } | New-Item
New-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\keith\Documents' is denied.
At line:5 char:5
+ } | New-Item
+     ~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Users\keith\Documents:String) [New
   -Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Comm
   ands.NewItemCommand
```

Comment: Yes but the content will be a stringified version of the object not the property value

Comment: LOL, you're right, I didn't check the file content! I've never seen a pipeline object do "double-duty" before. Live and learn!

Comment: What happens is that the `Path` parameter is bound by `PropertyName` (because the parameter type is `System.String[]`) but then the whole object is bound by Value to the `Value` parameter (because it's type is `System.Object`)

Comment: Exactly, I didn't write that example initially, but it also happened to me XD